# javafx table view is not showing any data from database

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I created a book management application via javafx. Through this app we can perform add, search and delete operations. For the search i am using Table view to get all the details of the book searched by the user. So in the end i am getting the result displayed in the console but not in the table view

```
   package Managemnet;

   import java.sql.Connection;

   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;


  import connection.*;
  import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
  import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
  import javafx.fxml.FXML;

  import javafx.scene.control.Button;

  import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
  import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
   import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
  import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
  import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

   public class Searching {



Connection connect;
@FXML
TableView<Book> search_view ;
@FXML
ObservableList<Book> observeList;

@FXML
TableColumn<Book, Integer> Book_I;
@FXML
TableColumn<Book, String> Book_n;
@FXML
TableColumn<Book, String> publish;
@FXML
TableColumn<Book, Integer> ye;
@FXML
TextField sea_Book_name;
@FXML
TextField sea_pub;
@FXML
TextField sea_year;
@FXML
AnchorPane SearchPane;
@FXML
Button search;

public void search() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    
    Sql_query sql = new Sql_query();
    sql.connect_sql();
    connect = sql.getConnect();
    observeList = FXCollections.<Book>observableArrayList();
    search_view = new TableView<Book>();
    
    Book_I=new TableColumn<Book ,Integer>();
    Book_I.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book ,Integer>
    ("Book_id"));
    
    Book_n=new TableColumn<Book ,String>();
    Book_n.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book ,String>
    ("Book_name"));
    
    publish=new TableColumn<Book ,String>();
    publish.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book ,String>
    ("Publisher"));
    
    ye=new TableColumn<Book ,Integer>();
    ye.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book ,Integer>("year"));
    
    
    
    String s1= sea_Book_name.getText();
    String s2= sea_pub.getText();
    String s= sea_year.getText();
    
    int s3;
    if(!s.isEmpty()){
        s3=Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    else s3=0;
    
    ResultSet res;
    
    Answer_from_dataset obj= new Answer_from_dataset();
    res=obj.getAnswer(s1, s2, s3);
    
    while(res.next()){
    
    observeList.add(new Book(res.getInt(1), res.getString(2), 
    res.getString(3), res.getInt(4)));
    //System.out.println(observeList);
     }
    search_view.setItems(observeList);
    System.out.println(search_view);
    
        }
```

```
      package Managemnet;

      import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
     import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

 public class Book {

 SimpleStringProperty Book_name;
 SimpleStringProperty Publisher;
 SimpleIntegerProperty Book_id;
 SimpleIntegerProperty year;

public Book(int book_id, String book_name, String publisher, int year) {
    
    this.Book_name =new SimpleStringProperty(book_name);
    this.Publisher =new SimpleStringProperty(publisher);
    this.Book_id =new SimpleIntegerProperty (book_id);
    this.year = new SimpleIntegerProperty(year);
        
}

public String getBook_name() {
    return Book_name.get();
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return Publisher.get();
}

public Integer getBook_id() {
    return Book_id.get();
}

public Integer getYear() {
    return year.get();
}

public void setBook_name(String book_name) {
    Book_name.set(book_name);
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    Publisher.set(publisher);;
}

public void setBook_id(int book_id) {
    Book_id.set(book_id);;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year.set(year);;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getBook_id() + " " + getBook_name() + " " + getPublisher() + " " 
+ getYear();
}






   }
```

Comment: You create a new table view and new table columns every time you search...

Comment: Try to remove `search_view=new TableView<Book>();`

Comment: @mrmcwolf and similarly for the table columns...

Comment: Hey James_D & Mcwolf,
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this issue with FXML when I did my first project with JavaFX.

I tried a lot of solutions with FXML but it took time and nothing worked. So I shifted over to using POJO's. This may not be ideally what you're looking for but it would give you a pretty good amount of flexibility with creating your table.

Ideally for the table itself you want to create a TableView

```
TableView<Book> table = new TableView();
```

Then for each column you want to create a TableColumn.. Now here you need to be careful

```
TableColumn<Book, String> col1 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
col.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().getName()));
```

The values within the angle brackets is <Object Type, Data Type>

And then of course you can set your preferred width and what not. But the same process of creating TableColumns Repeats itself for the table you have. I get this might be a little more of lengthier process but its relatively easy to understand and most importantly it work.

Try this and let me know if it works! Cheers!!

Comment: the _nothing worked_ isn't implicit for the fxml approach, it's just an indication that you did something wrong :) Nor is using a Pojo exclusive to the manual coding approach, in fact you need it anyway.